# Adding Styles to RTE (CQ5.4)

Tags: aem, rte

I am using 5.4. I'm attempting to add a style to the drop down style box on the rte. I followed the instructions found on http://docs.adobe.com/docs/en/cq/5-4/administering/configuring_rich_text_editor.html. After adding the node under text/rtePlugins/styles/styles, all of the options for the plugin are disabled. The buttons (such as the bold, italics, underline, etc...) are no longer clickable. While I can still select styles from the paraformat and style drop downs, they do not change the appearance of my text. Moreover, although I can change the text in the rte, the changes are not reflected in the page after I click ok.

I have attached a snapshot of my node hierarchy for the dialog node. Please let me know if I should include any other information.

[image]

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Did you create this whole structure by yourself or copy it from somewhere?
What you need to be sure is to enable some features per type (or all by using *):

Here an example for the styles node:

```
<styles
    jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured"
    features="*">
    <styles jcr:primaryType="cq:WidgetCollection">
    [...]
    </styles>
</styles>
```

This has to be true for all the other nodes, but if you do not copy them at all you should have all features active again as well.

For having your custom style available in the RTE you also need to provide a CSS file on the text node with the following property.

```
externalStyleSheets="[{path_to_your_stylesheet}]"
```

I recommend to create one just for the RTE with just the styles you add in the styles list.

Comment: I created the structure myself. I did enable all features by using *.
I also provided the CSS file on my text node, and I have attempted to use clientlibs to reference the style sheet. I will attempt to create a separate style sheet for the styles in the styles list.

Comment: The separate style sheet did not help.

Comment: Could you provide a content package with your text component and the referenced CSS? Maybe I find the time to have a closer look though I currently only have running 5.6.1 instances at my disposal. But as far as I remember there weren't any changes regarding RTE.

Answer (score 1):

I followed the instructions here, and it worked for me:
http://docs.adobe.com/docs/en/cq/5-4/administering/configuring_rich_text_editor.html#Styles (Text)

The resulting dialog looked like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jcr:root xmlns:cq="http://www.day.com/jcr/cq/1.0" xmlns:jcr="http://www.jcp.org/jcr/1.0" xmlns:nt="http://www.jcp.org/jcr/nt/1.0"
jcr:primaryType="cq:Dialog"
externalStyleSheets="[/etc/designs/myDesign/css/my_colors.css]"
height="500"
width="700"
xtype="dialog">
    <items
    jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured"
    helpPath="en/cq/current/wcm/default_components.html#Text"
    title="Text"
    xtype="tabpanel">
    <items jcr:primaryType="cq:WidgetCollection">
        <tab1
            jcr:primaryType="cq:Widget"
            anchor="100%"
            height="350"
            title="Text"
            xtype="panel">
            <items jcr:primaryType="cq:WidgetCollection">
                <text
                    jcr:primaryType="cq:Widget"
                    allowBlank="false"
                    blankText=""
                    disabled="false"
                    emptyText=""
                    fieldDescription=""
                    fieldLabel=""
                    fieldSubLabel=""
                    grow="false"
                    height="{Long}350"
                    hideLabel="true"
                    hideMode=""
                    inputType=""
                    maxLength=""
                    maxLengthText=""
                    minLength=""
                    minLengthText=""
                    msgTarget=""
                    name="./text"
                    readOnly="false"
                    regex=""
                    regexText=""
                    selectOnFocus="false"
                    validateOnBlur="true"
                    validationDelay=""
                    validationEvent=""
                    validator=""
                    vtype=""
                    vtypeText=""
                    xtype="richtext">
                    <rtePlugins jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured">
                        <links jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured">
                            <linkDialogConfig
                                jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured"
                                height="316">
                                <linkAttributes jcr:primaryType="cq:WidgetCollection">
                                    <linkAdvanced
                                        jcr:primaryType="cq:Widget"
                                        collapsed="true"
                                        collapsible="true"
                                        inputValue="advanced"
                                        name="./linkdialog/cq:adhocLinkTrackingTab"
                                        title="Link tracking"
                                        xtype="dialogfieldset">
                                        <items jcr:primaryType="cq:WidgetCollection">
                                            <enable
                                                jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured"
                                                attribute="enabletracking"
                                                fieldDescription="override analytics framework settings"
                                                fieldLabel="Custom link tracking"
                                                name="./linkdialog/cq:adhocLinkTrackingEnableTracking"
                                                xtype="checkbox">
                                                <listeners
                                                    jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured"
                                                    check="function(component){var dlg=component.findParentByType('rtelinkdialog');dlg.enableSCFields(component.checked);}"/>
                                            </enable>
                                            <events
                                                jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured"
                                                attribute="adhocevents"
                                                fieldDescription="e.g.: event2, event7"
                                                fieldLabel="Include SiteCatalyst events"
                                                name="./linkdialog/cq:adhocLinkTrackingEvents"
                                                xtype="textfield"/>
                                            <evars
                                                jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured"
                                                attribute="adhocevars"
                                                fieldDescription="e.g.: eVar1: pagedata.url, prop4: 'const'"
                                                fieldLabel="Include SiteCatalyst variables"
                                                name="./linkdialog/cq:adhocLinkTrackingEvars"
                                                xtype="textfield"/>
                                        </items>
                                    </linkAdvanced>
                                </linkAttributes>
                            </linkDialogConfig>
                        </links>
                        <misctools
                            jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured"
                            features="*"/>
                        <edit
                            jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured"
                            features="*"/>
                        <findreplace
                            jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured"
                            features="*"/>
                        <format
                            jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured"
                            features="*"/>
                        <image
                            jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured"
                            features="*"/>
                        <keys
                            jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured"
                            features="*"/>
                        <justify
                            jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured"
                            features="*"/>
                        <lists
                            jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured"
                            features="*"/>
                        <paraformat
                            jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured"
                            features="*"/>
                        <spellcheck
                            jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured"
                            features="*"/>
                        <styles
                            jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured"
                            features="*">
                            <styles jcr:primaryType="cq:WidgetCollection">
                                <Aqua
                                    jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured"
                                    cssName="Aqua"
                                    text="Aqua"/>
                            </styles>
                        </styles>
                        <subsuperscript
                            jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured"
                            features="*"/>
                        <table
                            jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured"
                            features="*"/>
                        <undo
                            jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured"
                            features="*"/>
                    </rtePlugins>
                </text>
                <isRichTextFlag
                    jcr:primaryType="cq:Widget"
                    ignoreData="true"
                    name="./textIsRich"
                    value="true"
                    xtype="hidden"/>
            </items>
        </tab1>
        <tab2
            jcr:primaryType="cq:Widget"
            xtype="componentstyles"/>
    </items>
</items>
</jcr:root>
```

The only items added to the original dialog, was the "externalStyleSheets" attribute on the "jcr:root" node (you should map this to your style sheet):

```
externalStyleSheets="[/etc/designs/myDesign/css/my_colors.css]"
```

And the  node:

> ```
>     <styles
>          jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured"
>          features="*">
>          <styles jcr:primaryType="cq:WidgetCollection">
>              <Aqua
>                 jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured"
>                 cssName="Aqua"
>                 text="Aqua"/>
>          </styles>
>     </styles>
> ```

The "cssName" attribute must match your css style name (and NOT be preceeded by a "."), the  "text" attribute can be anything you want, it will be what appears in the drop-down.

my_colors.css looks like this:

```
.Aqua { color: Aqua; }
```

Hope this helps,

-- Joel.